# Zurich font is not working in Internet explorer

Tags: css, fonts, stylesheet, font-face

I downloaded an TTF file for ZURCH font from the internet and it worked fine in  FF and Chrome. But did not work in ie.

Can someone tell me the reason, or how to solve it?

Comment: Which exact TTF file did you download, so we can have a look. And did you install it on your system? Did it work normally (i.e. for other programs like Notepad, etc.)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/314344/user314344?tab=questions take a look here. Do you see some red font?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the fonts on the same domain as the website you are using them on.

Make sure your css looks something like this for cross-browser compatibility, especially the line that contains #iefix :

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('WebFont.eot');
src: url('WebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('WebFont.woff') format('woff'),
url('WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Make sure that the url to the WebFonts is also correct

```
src: url('../path_to_fonts/WebFont.ttf');
```

If you need to convert the ttf to the other formats ie. woff, eot and svg, try [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: OP didn't ask about web fonts.

Comment: @MrLister Check out the tags. "CSS", "stylesheet", and "font-face" seem to contradict your comment. :)

Comment: Looks like a webfont question to me if he's trying to view it in a browser... maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Oh, OK. But the wording in the question is still somewhat ambiguous.